# Как в grafana указать что бы он в dasboard брал статистику с prometeus?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

Вопрос может быть очень простой, но я только второй день с этим разбираюсь и не понимаю где взять ответ.

Есть docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2.1'

networks:
  monitor-net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  prometheus_data: {}
  grafana_data: {}

services:

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.43.0
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles'
      - '--storage.tsdb.retention.time=200h'
      - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
    restart: unless-stopped
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    expose:
      - 9090
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  alertmanager:
    image: prom/alertmanager:v0.25.0
    container_name: alertmanager
    volumes:
      - ./alertmanager:/etc/alertmanager
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/alertmanager/config.yml'
      - '--storage.path=/alertmanager'
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9093
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  nodeexporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter:v1.5.0
    container_name: nodeexporter
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
    command:
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc'
      - '--path.rootfs=/rootfs'
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - '--collector.filesystem.mount-points-exclude=^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc)($$|/)'
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9100
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  cadvisor:
    image: gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor:v0.47.1
    container_name: cadvisor
    privileged: true
    devices:
      - /dev/kmsg:/dev/kmsg
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:ro
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:ro
      #- /cgroup:/cgroup:ro #doesn't work on MacOS only for Linux
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 8080
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:7.2.0
    container_name: grafana
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
      - ./grafana/provisioning/dashboards:/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards
      - ./grafana/provisioning/datasources:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=${ADMIN_USER:-admin}
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD:-admin}
      - GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=false
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 3000
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  pushgateway:
    image: prom/pushgateway:v1.5.1
    container_name: pushgateway
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9091
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  caddy:
    image: caddy:2.6.4
    container_name: caddy
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "9090:9090"
      - "9093:9093"
      - "9091:9091"
    volumes:
      - ./caddy:/etc/caddy
    environment:
      - ADMIN_USER=${ADMIN_USER:-admin}
      - ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD:-admin}
      - ADMIN_PASSWORD_HASH=${ADMIN_PASSWORD_HASH:-$2a$14$1l.IozJx7xQRVmlkEQ32OeEEfP5mRxTpbDTCTcXRqn19gXD8YK1pO}
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"
```

Я запускаю все доккер образы и все поднимается.

Есть сервер на node.js котоый запускается pm2.

- С pm2 собирается статистика, которая собирается prometeus
- Для графиков для prometeus добавляется grafana
- pm2 выводит метрики по адресу http://localhost:4422
- Prometeus поднимается в докере и весит на порту Http://localhost:9090

В конфиге prometeus я добавляю службу

```
  - job_name: pm2-metrics
    scrape_interval: 10s
    scrape_timeout: 10s
    metrics_path: "/metrics"
    scheme: http
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:4422'] // localhost
```

Если я в нем указываю localhost до с зостовой машины, в localgost не видно в доккере.

В интерене я нашел решение, добавление в prometeus

```
   extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Это дает возможность получить доступ к хосту

Так хост появляется в prometeus и он показывает что поднят и я получаю метрики.

```
http://host.docker.internal:4422/metrics    UP  
instance="host.docker.internal:9209"job="pm2-metrics"
```

Но когда я запускаю grafana и преднастроенные мониторы, он не видит prometeus

Где в grafana подключить prometeus ?